# LINQ: Order collection by Group Count

Tags: c#, linq, count

Say I have a collection of Person objects, and each person has a hair color property (values are: Blonde, Black, Brown, Red, White).

How can I use LINQ to re-order these Person objects according to their group counts (in descending order)?

Example:

**Bob (Brown), Jack (Blonde), Mark (Brown), Bill (White), George (Brown), Jim (Blonde), Thomas (Red)**

Should be-reordered to:

**Bob (Brown), Mark (Brown), George (Brown), Jack (Blonde), Jim (Blonde), Bill (White), Thomas (Red)**

Performance is a key concern here as well, so the fewest lines of code would be preferable.

Comment: Key takeaway: Lines of Code !== Performance.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm confused aren't thomas supposed to be before bill in the second listen?!

Comment: For more clarity, if you do a group by on the above example by hair color, you would get: 
Brown 3
Blonde 2
White 1
Red 1

Therefore, if re-ordering by descending order, it should list the Brown haired people first, then the Blondes, then Whites/Reds (as demonstrated in the above example).

Comment: @ZiggY - If you edit your question to be more specific, and to include your current attempt at solving this problem then we should be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this works:

```
List<Person> persons =
    new List<Person>() {
    new Person("Bob", "Brown"),
    new Person("Jack", "Blonde"),
    new Person("Mark", "Brown"),
    new Person("Bill", "White"),
    new Person("George", "Brown"),
    new Person("Jim", "Blonde"),
    new Person("Thomas", "Red")
};

foreach (var a in persons.GroupBy(p => p.HairColor).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).SelectMany(g => g)) {
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Where...

```
public class Person {
    public Person(string name, string hairColor) {
        Name = name;
        HairColor = hairColor;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HairColor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name + " (" + HairColor + ")";
    }
}
```